# How to grep between third appear and fourth appear

Tags: linux, grep

I tried to get "hello" ,but this not work ,it between third and fourth appear of character `i`

```
echo "ixaifsdaihelloihd" | grep -oP '(?=i{3}).*?(?=i{4})'
```

Comment: Maybe `awk -F'i' '{print $4}' <<< "ixaifsdaihelloihd"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you do it with grep ?

Comment: `echo "ixaifsdaihelloihd" | grep -oP '^(?:[^i]*i){3}\K[^i]+'`

Comment: can you explain a bit with that grep ,if the fourth appear `i` is `z` as `ixaifsdaihellozhd` , can you get `hello`

Comment: `echo "ixaifsdaihellozhd" | grep -oP '^(?:[^i]*i){3}\K.*?(?=z)' ` ,tks much @WiktorStribiżew ,i did it with your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
echo "ixaifsdaihelloihd" | cut -d'i' -f4
```

Comment: short ..... good

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "ixaifsdaihelloihd" | grep -oP '^(?:[^i]*i){3}\K[^i]+'
```

or

```
awk -F'i' '{print $4}' <<< "ixaifsdaihelloihd"
```

Answer (score 1):

if u need the `z`

> ```
> echo "ixaifsdaihellozhd" | 
>
> {m,g}awk -Fi 'sub("z.*$", substr(_,$!_=$4))'
> ```

```
 hello
```

if just `i`'s :

> ```
>  mawk -Fi '$!NF=$4'
>
>  nawk -Fi '$-_=$4'
>
>  gawk -Fi '$_=$4'
> ```